# How to describe all the direct sum of Z module $ Z \oplus Z_{2}$?

Tags: ring-theory

I have a question saying "describe all the direct sum of Z module $ Z \oplus Z_{2}$". can somebody help me solve this? I don't know how to even begin here

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know what $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ is, or that you know what it is but are unsure what the word "describe" is asking for?

Comment: Also, does the exercise really say "all" in the place it does? That doesn't look grammatical to me.

Comment: @HenningMakholm both actually

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm translating, but yes it does

Comment: Do you know what a $\mathbb Z$-module is? Do you know how $\mathbb Z$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module? Do you know what $\mathbb Z_2$ is? Do you know what a direct sum is?

Comment: Which language are you translating from? Please provide the original wording of the exercise.